# GrapQl (ZeroQL) mutation multiple inserting

Tags: graphql

trying to do for mutation in GraphQL, first one its working fine, again try to one more created so I'm getting error for second one I was done in this way I shared all my code.
error: There was no argument with the name `ShareSettingsModel` found on the field `createEventShareSettings

```
mutation {
  createEventShareSettings(shareSettingsModel:{
    id:0,
    eventId:1,
    approxRevenueForCurrentYear:true,
    typeOfFunding:true,
    preMoneyValuation:true,
    typeOfOffering:true,
    
    
  }){
    id
  }
}

[Authorize]
    public async Task<EventShareSettings> CreateEventShareSettings([Service] DataContext _context, [Service] IJwtAuth jwtAuth, [Service] IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor,  EventShareSettingsModel ShareSettingsModel)
    {
        var claims = jwtAuth.GetClaimsData(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);

        var _sharedSettings = await _context.EventShareSettings.FirstOrDefaultAsync(_ => _.EventId == ShareSettingsModel.EventId && _.Id== ShareSettingsModel.Id);
        if (_sharedSettings == null)
        {
                _sharedSettings = new EventShareSettings
            {
                EventId = ShareSettingsModel.EventId,
                ApproxRevenueForCurrentYear = ShareSettingsModel.ApproxRevenueForCurrentYear,
                PreMoneyValuation = ShareSettingsModel.PreMoneyValuation,
                TypeOfFunding = ShareSettingsModel.TypeOfFunding,
                TypeOfOffering = ShareSettingsModel.TypeOfOffering,
               
            };
            _context.EventShareSettings.Add(_sharedSettings);
        }
        else
        {
            _sharedSettings.ApproxRevenueForCurrentYear = ShareSettingsModel.ApproxRevenueForCurrentYear;
            _sharedSettings.PreMoneyValuation = ShareSettingsModel.PreMoneyValuation;
            _sharedSettings.TypeOfFunding = ShareSettingsModel.TypeOfFunding;
            _sharedSettings.TypeOfOffering = ShareSettingsModel.TypeOfOffering;
            
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return _sharedSettings;
    }

            services.AddGraphQLServer()
                .AddAuthorization()
                .AddFiltering()
                .AddSorting()
                .AddProjections()
                .AddType<MutationType>()
                .AddType<ShareSettingsMutationType>()
                .AddQueryType<Query>()
                .AddMutationType<Mutation>();
            services.AddGraphQLServer().AddMutationConventions(applyToAllMutations: true);

public class MutationType : ObjectType<EventAndPollsRequestModel>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<EventAndPollsRequestModel> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Field(a => a.EventId).Type<IdType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.EventName).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.Description).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.StartDate).Type<DateTimeType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.EndDate).Type<DateTimeType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.TimeZone).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.Address).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.InviteLink).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.Companies).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.EventImage).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.PollRequired).Type<BooleanType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.CompanyName).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.EventCode).Type<IdType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.Status).Type<IdType>();
        }
    }
    public class ShareSettingsMutationType : ObjectType<EventShareSettingsModel>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<EventShareSettingsModel> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Field(a => a.Id).Type<IdType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.EventId).Type<IdType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.ApproxRevenueForCurrentYear).Type<BooleanType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.PreMoneyValuation).Type<BooleanType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.TypeOfOffering).Type<BooleanType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.PreMoneyValuation).Type<BooleanType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.TypeOfOffering).Type<BooleanType>();
           
        }
    }
```